# Should I answer if it is not a perfect answer?

Tags: discussion

A user asks a question and I have an answer. Now I know that it is not a perfect answer to the question(my own limited knowledge) but provides enough details and context on the subject. Adding it as comment doesn't help as I need formatting and probably it will be over the word limit.

I think I should answer as it still adds to the knowledge base, and might actually help the user. What does community think?

Comment: "but provides enough details and context on the subject" Enough details *to what*?  For readers of the question with that problem to understand and solve the problem?  Something else, if so what?

Comment: @Servy good point. For the readers of the question, which might actually help them to find their own answers.

Comment: We can't evaluate whether you should answer or not. You're asking us the equivalent of *Please debug my code* without the code. If you feel you have an appropriate answer, post it. If you don't have one, don't post. If you're not sure, you'll have to decide for yourself.

Comment: I haven't seen a "perfect" answer on SO yet.  But if there is one, it probably mentions unicorns and Jon Skeet.  In fact, it would probably have to be written by Jon Skeet, and be [about Jon Skeet](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-34596634).

Answer (score 11):

If you're going to answer the question, **answer** the question.  Be as complete and thorough as the question requires.

Comment: What if I am limited by my own knowledge and experience. I did try my best to research before answering though. I have changed the question to make my intent clearer

Comment: I maintain my position.  If you're concerned that you don't know enough to sufficiently answer the question, it's best *not* to answer the question until you *do* have that knowledge.

Comment: If you don't know if your answer is going to be useful or not, wait until an hour after the question was posted.  Has someone else done a good enough job?  If so, move on, but if not, post yours.  It's better than nothing, right?

Comment: @user2554330 This was my intention. The question is unanswered from several hours, mostly because it is a very niche topic. I intended to help asker since he seems completely lost.

Comment: Right.  If someone else can improve on your answer, maybe they will, maybe they won't.  But the questioner will be better off with your effort than if you wait until your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

It is always good idea to check [help: how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (highlight is mine):

> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that **gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful**, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Even if your answer is not complete it must point to direction of valid answer. In most cases when you are not sure what answer should be there is no way to know if suggestion you have at the moment actually is *the right direction*. There is no good reason to post such suggestion as an answer (maybe comment, but even then what use of it on the question?).

On other hand if you know that what you have is *an answer*, but you are not sure if it is the best (in whatever way you fancy it), the most complete,... - you are welcome to post it as an answer. Make sure to include limitations/problems with your approach. Please accept the fact that your answer may be completely against all good practices or just simply bad and could be voted as such.

Comment: Guess I should have revisited the section. Yup I did mention what is missing, what can be improved. I will this is good for community to some subjective extent.